# Android : What to use for width/height in layerlist items for Android API less than 21

Tags: android, xml, layer-list

I've created a splash screen, with an image that resizes well on API >=21, but gets broken below than version.

**Following is the xml.**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="#4F9FFB"/>
    </item>
    <item
        android:width="70dp"
        android:height="70dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Breaks because `android:width="70dp"`  and `android:height="70dp"` are not supported below `21`.

What's the alternative for this?

Comment: can you post the expected out put ?

Comment: @Charuka Ok coming through.

Comment: inside your item add this and see <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />